# how to get Latitude and Longitude like search in google map

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

I want to display Latitude and Longitude on my page like we search in google map,for example if i enter Comfort Inn Sunset then it show the Latitude and Longitude in textbox.

so please help me as soon as possible.

Comment: the urgency to which you need help won't get you a response any quicker. I don't think many look at a question and thinks of something and doesn't say.. You probably need to attach a GPS

Comment: you really should clarify your question. And you really should find out some basic english words, like ADDRESS.

Comment: What have you done so far, by yourself? Did your read some of the [Google Maps API Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the link below.

http://jsfiddle.net/nB2ej/

```
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': addresscity }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                    document.getElementById("lat").value=   latitude;
                   document.getElementById("lon").value=   longitude; 
                 var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    var mapOptions = {
                 center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
                  zoom: 8,
                 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

             };
});
```

Comment: thanks rgs it work nice but do you have some more example of this i use one example in that it dont give proper answer.

Comment: please refer this link also. This one is customized map.http://jsfiddle.net/UeP2f/

Comment: Please check this also. http://jsfiddle.net/xJ26V/1/. This example will find distance from the searching location.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it manually on sites like:

http://stevemorse.org/jcal/latlon.php?cookie=&hidden=&doextra=&time=1253907285187&addr2latlon=1&address=508+Tremont+Ave.+S.W.+Apt.+3R+Building+behind+first+row+-+Upstairs&city=Massillon&state=OH&zip=44647&country=US&latlon2addr=0&latitude=&longitude=

or

http://stuff.mit.edu/geo?location=New+york%2Cnew+york

Comment: but i want only latitude and longitude in this when i enter only name like in google map, in this we enter any location name and display this location in pin same as i want for latitude and longitude.